# Magento2: run cron job every minute

Tags: magento2, cron

System cron starts Magento 2 cron every minute:

```
$ crontab -l
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/user/prj/mage2/bin/magento cron:run >> /home/user/prj/mage2/var/log/cron.log
```

I see new line `Ran jobs by schedule.` is added every minute into the log.

This is my settings for my task:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="my_own" instance="\Vendor\Module\Cron\Task" method="execute">
            <schedule>...</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

These settings run my job every 15 minutes in fact (my own message is added every 15 minutes into the log):

```
<schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
<schedule>*/1 * * * *</schedule>
```

This is my log:

```
...
Ran jobs by schedule.
Ran jobs by schedule.
Ran jobs by schedule.
My own job is started.
Ran jobs by schedule.
...
```

These are Magento 2 cron settings:
[image: Magento 2 Cron settings]

How can I set `<schedule>` to run my task every 1 minute?

Comment: This should works fine `<schedule>* * * * *</schedule>`

Comment: In fact `<schedule>* * * * *</schedule>` runs my task every 15 min :(

Comment: Something is wrong on ur server. It should work globally as 1 minute.

Comment: Yes, it is :( System cron (linux) starts every minute and launches Magento 2 cron every minute but Magento cron launches my own task just once in 15 min for `<schedule>* * * * *</schedule>` Probably, there are some Magento 2 configuration settings that prevent launch tasks more, then once in 15 min?

Comment: Check in `cron_schedule` table

Comment: I've checked `cron_schedule` table - my task is launched every 15 min for `*/1 * * * *` schedule. I have 4 records for my task - scheduled_at: 6:04:00, 6:19:00, 6:34:00, 6:49:00;  executed_at: 6:05:09, 6:20:09, 6:35:09, 6:50:11. No tasks with pending status found.

Answer (score 9):

There are 2 groups in Magento 2 cron: `index` & `default`. Tasks/jobs are placed into `index` group will start every 1 minute (by default setup):

```
<group id="index">
    <job name="..." instance="..." method="...">
        <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
    </job>
</group>
```

Tasks/jobs are placed into `default` group will start every 15 minutes (by default setup):

```
<group id="default">
    <job name="..." instance="..." method="...">
        <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
    </job>
</group>
```

Comment: Is there any configuration settings for these?

Comment: Stores / Configuration / Advanced / System / Cron (Scheduled Tasks) / Cron configuration options for group: [index|default]

Comment: i have setup group id index for every minutes and alredy run cron:run command but its not working for me

Answer (score 8):

It appears that cron jobs in Magento 2 are limited by their settings defined in the cron group they belong to. I'm not sure if this is a bug or a feature.

[Alex Gusev](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/33058/alex-gusev) already points this out in [his answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/161220/2030), but to clarify it a bit more: There are 2 cron groups by default in Magento 2: `default` and `index`. These are defined in `Magento_Indexer/etc/cron_groups.xml` and `Magento_Cron/etc/cron_groups.xml`. For example:

```
<group id="default">
    <schedule_generate_every>15</schedule_generate_every>
    <schedule_ahead_for>20</schedule_ahead_for>
    <schedule_lifetime>15</schedule_lifetime>
    <history_cleanup_every>10</history_cleanup_every>
    <history_success_lifetime>60</history_success_lifetime>
    <history_failure_lifetime>600</history_failure_lifetime>
    <use_separate_process>0</use_separate_process>
</group>
```

These cron group determine the default / global values of every cron job. I'm not sure how it works but according to my own tests you cannot set a cron to run more often per hour than determined in the `schedule_generate_every`-setting. So for example, if you have something like this:

```
<group id="default">
    <job name="custom_module" instance="Custom\Module\Cron\DoSomething" method="execute">
        <schedule>*/1 * * * *</schedule>
    </job>
</group>
```

Even though you **might expect that this cronjob is scheduled every minute**, it's **global settings limit it to a minimum timeframe of 15 minutes**.

To solve this, you can either:

- Edit the setting in the system configuration (Advanced → System → Cron), or:
- Override the global default in your module by adding a `cron_groups.xml`-file of your own (assuming that the client did not already tinker with the configuration settings):

Example `config_groups.xml`-file:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/cron_groups.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <schedule_generate_every>1</schedule_generate_every>
    </group>
</config>
```

Bug? Feature? Misleading configuration setting? I'm not sure how to call this. You could argue that it's a good thing that you have a global scope that can limit 100+ modules to try to run a cron every minute. On the other hand: If I'm a developer who knows what he's doing, there might be good reasons to run every minute.

If running every minute is mandatory it might also be an idea to add a whole new cron group for your configuration (don't pollute the `index`-cron group with non-indexing cron jobs). But that's a matter of architecture and I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: I don't think that is correct. The `schedule_generate_every` tells Magento to update the schedule for this cron group every 15 mins. If you set a job to run every minute in that group then Magento would generate 15 `cron_schedule` entries for that job, one for each minute.

Comment: I would expect that too, but these are the results I observed at the time. I'm not even sure which Magento version it was anymore. 2.0? 2.1? Results may differ in the meanwhile. I was also questioning whether this was a bug or a feature.

Answer (score 4):

To schedule once per minute, need to give

* * * * *

From Left to right,
1st star represents Minute(range: 0-59)
2nd represents Hour(range: 0-23)
3rd represents Day of the Month  (range: 1-31)
4th represents Month of the Year (range: 1-12)
5th represents Day of the Week   (range: 1-7, 1 standing for Monday)

Refer Link for cron timing : http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/working/cron-format.htm

Reference Link for setting custom cron : http://www.dckap.com/blog/how-to-set-and-configure-custom-cron-jobs-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear from your question which schedule you want, so here are both:

**Every 1 minute:**

```
* * * * *
```

**Every 15 minutes:**

```
*/15 * * * *
```

You may find this tool useful for creating/debugging cron schedules: https://crontab.guru/

Comment: I have added an "echo" statement in my task and echoed message appears every 15 min for "* * * * *" schedule. So, in fact this settings runs my task every 15 min., not every minute.

Comment: Check your configuration under Stores > Configuration > Advanced > System > Cron (Scheduled Tasks). Make sure the schedule settings are OK for your setup.

Comment: All settings are unchanged (set by default).

Comment: Hi Danny Nimmo, Its working when i am running cron:run command. That's mean every time i am running cron:run command than its working

Answer (score 0):

Please Try

> */1 * * * *

for scheduling cron at each minute.
You can check your cron entries in the cron_schedule table to see the scheduling entries done by Magento.

Answer (score 0):

Please add * * * * * in your schedule tag in xml file.