# how to run work crons every 15 min

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, magento-cron

I have many tasks cron, and for each indicate the path and time not too good

I know about `cron.sh` file. 
On my server, I have a scheduled task, and I would like to set the launch every 15 minutes on this file, and will it automatically launch my crowns to me or not?

Will the queue be respected, will the cron settings which I set in `config.xml`  files.

Comment: follow this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/161168/magento2-run-cron-job-every-minute

Answer (score 0):

you can follow the link to seup cron as per your require time.

https://www.easycron.com/faq/What-cron-expression-does-easycron-support

And for Magento code you can follow this one.

https://inchoo.net/magento/creating-cron-script-in-magento/